# Replacing time_ago_in_words with timeago jQuery plugin in i18n-ized Rails 3.2 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, railstutorial.org, timeago

Running my finished Rails Tutorial app through [Rails Best Practices](http://railsbp.com/) got me a warning to [not use the `time_ago_in_words` method](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/105-not-use-time_ago_in_words) as "it's too expensive to calculate the time on the server side", so they provide some example code to change your implementation to use the [timeago jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/).  Sounded like it would make an interesting change, so I attempted it.  My original code that used `time_ago_in_words` is in two places:

**app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.haml**

```
# ...
%span.timestamp
  = t('.time_posted_ago', time: time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) )
```

**app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.haml**

```
# ...
%span.timestamp
  = t('.time_posted_ago', time: time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at))
```

I changed the code to use timeago as follows, using the HTML5 `time` tag:

**app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.haml**

```
# ...
%time.timeago{ datetime: feed_item.created_at.getutc.iso8601 }
  = t('.time_posted_ago', time: feed_item.created_at.to_s)
```

**app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.haml**

```
# ...
%time.timeago{ datetime: micropost.created_at.getutc.iso8601 }
  = t('.time_posted_ago', time: micropost.created_at.to_s)
```

Which, I thought, only left me to add the timeago() method to my coffeescript file:

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("time.timeago").timeago()
```

This didn't work, so I tried moving the statement to **microposts.js.coffee** and **users.js.coffee**, with and without `$(document).ready ->` and still no go.  I then thought that perhaps the required libraries for timeago aren't included by default in `jquery-rails`, so I added them:

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.min
//= require jquery.timeago
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Adding the `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.timeago.js` declarations here didn't work, and I'm also assuming my syntax is off since they busted my other page elements that rely on javascript.

So, as far as I understand, I think I have the implementation code correct in my haml files, but I just don't know:

1. in which coffeescript file I should put the `$("time.timeago").timeago()` call and how I should write it if what I have is incorrect
2. whether `timeago` libraries are included in rails-jquery
3. if they're not, how to include them properly

After spending a lot of time on this, I did end up trying out the [rails-timeago](https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago) gem, which, as well as having some nice helpers, did work in getting the time to display properly.  However, it didn't seem to play well with the rails `t()` method implementation above in order to just get the time in words and then interpolate it in to an i18n string.

So, how can I get the desired effect of `time_ago_in_words` using the timeago JQuery plugin in a Rails 3.2 app with i18n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to hack together a solution using the [rails-timeago gem](https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago).  It's not optimal, but it seems to get the desired timeago effect, which is quite nice.  I'd like to know how to get the same effect in Rails using just the [timeago jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) and the `%time.timeago` tags.  Anyway, hopefully this is of interest to someone.

#### Setup

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails-timeago', '1.3.0'
```

**config/initializers/timeago.rb**

```
Rails::Timeago.default_options limit: proc { 20.days.ago }, nojs: true
Rails::Timeago.locales = [:en, :it, :ja]
```

Create **app/assets/javascripts/locales** directory to put customizations to the timeago i18n strings.  For completeness sake, I took the three locales I wanted for my app from the [jQuery-timeago Github repository](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/tree/master/locales) and put them under the directory, but only actually ended up changing the ja locale file.

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
# ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-timeago
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.haml**

```
# ...
%head
  # ...
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = timeago_script_tag
```

#### Implementation

**app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.haml**

```
# ...
%span.timestamp
  = t('.time_posted_prefix')
  %time<
    = timeago_tag(micropost.created_at)
    = t('.time_posted_suffix')
```

Code for **app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.haml** is the same: just substitute out `micropost` for `feed_item`.

#### i18n

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
microposts:
  micropost:
    time_posted_prefix: Posted
    time_posted_suffix: ""
```

**config/locales/it.yml**

```
microposts:
  micropost:
    time_posted_prefix: Pubblicato
    time_posted_suffix: ""
```

**config/locales/ja.yml**

```
microposts:
  micropost:
    time_posted_prefix: ""
    time_posted_suffix: に投稿された。
```

Strings for `shared.feed_item` in the i18n files are the same.

I couldn't find a way to use `t()` dynamically with the result of `timeago_tag` (eg `t('.time_posted_ago', time: timeago_tag(micropost.created_at))`), so I put the result between a prefix and a suffix.  timeago provides time-related prefixes/suffixes, but not ones related to "posting", so they were added above.
In order to get rid of the space between the output of `timeago_tag` and `time_posted_suffix` (specifically for Japanese), I wrapped those two tags in a `%time<` tag with a `<` to [remove all whitespace within the tag](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).  It's a small thing, but it was annoying for me so I wanted to put it in, but it's by no means necessary if you aren't using languages that would need a value in the `time_posted_suffix` key.  I'm also assuming there's a better way to do this.

#### Issues

I originally had **jquery.timeago.en.js**, **jquery.timeago.it.js**, and **jquery.timeago.ja.js** under the **app/assets/javascripts/locales** directory, but I had an issue where the en file didn't get loaded for the en locale; instead, the last file alphabetically in the directory, which was ja, would be used with the en locale.  So, I renamed the en file to **jquery.timeago.xx.js**, which got English to display.  I tried moving the en file outside the locales directory, but it never seemed to get picked up, so it became xx.

#### Update

The i18n issues I had are now solved.  See [this Github issue](https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago/issues/5) for details.  In summary, I got rid of my **app/assets/javascripts/locales** directory and put just **jquery.timeago.ja.js**, the only file I really wanted to customize, under the **lib/assets/javascripts/locales** directory, meaning that for `:it` and `:en` locales, `timeago`'s default translations get used, and `:en` translations display as expected.  So, I did get what I consider an good solution to this problem with the `rails-timeago` gem.

#### Update 2

This solution currently works locally, but does not deploy correctly to Heroku due to asset precompilation issues...

#### Update 3

Found a config solution that seems to work locally and with Heroku:

**config/initializers/timeago.rb**

```
Rails::Timeago.default_options limit: proc { 20.days.ago }, nojs: true
Rails::Timeago.locales = [:en, :it, :ja]
Rails::Timeago.map_locale "en", "jquery.timeago.js"  # default
Rails::Timeago.map_locale "it", "locales/jquery.timeago.it.js"  # default
Rails::Timeago.map_locale "ja", "timeago/jquery.timeago.ja.js"  # customized
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
# ...
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.timeago.js locales/jquery.timeago.it.js timeago/jquery.timeago.ja.js )
```

And, in this case, the only custom file needed is **app/assets/javascripts/timeago/jquery.timeago.ja.js**

Further details can be found at the [related Github issue](https://github.com/jgraichen/rails-timeago/issues/4).